# How to reinstall a CentOS 7 from the command line inside a VM?

Tags: centos, system-installation

How to reinstall a CentOS 7 from an ISO from the command line inside a VM ?

Comment: Normally (as blametheadmin answered) you'd boot the VM from the ISO. Are you asking for some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reinstall the CentOS OS from a shell prompt inside the OS itself. You need to reboot the VM from the ISO and then select the Install option just like you were doing a first install.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why this was negative. This is not new users friendly.